# Windows Service with timer 25 seconds later

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, timer

I have this simple windows service that is part of a browser game. What it does is check against database and if needed updates some rows. These actions takes about .5 to 1 second.

The data it reads is a date which tells if an item should be updated.

It works perfectly, however it is always around 25 seconds late. If I add an item to the queue, and that item is completed at 15:00:00, the service will update it at 15:00:25ish.

I've tried using threading.timer, a single thread and timers.timer and all works in the same way. I've also tried stopping the timer while the elapsed was running, although it takes less than a second so it should not be a problem.

I've also tried to attach the service to a debugger, and the same thing happens UNLESS I put a breakpoint. Then it happens as soon as it hits the breakpoint and i press f5 to continue.

Can anyone shed some light as to why the service seems to be behind? And a possible fix.

I was thinking I ran out of thread but I have a good 1000 left, so I'm kinda blank.

Please ask if you need more details, so I can provide.

I'm using .net 4.0 / C#

Threading.Thread

```
public partial class Service : ServiceBase
{
    Thread thread;

    public Service()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        thread = new Thread(DoWork);
        thread.Start();
    }

    private static void DoWork()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            //finish workingqueueitems
            WorkingQueue.ProcessFinishedItems();

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        thread.Abort();
    }
}
```

Timers.Timer

```
public partial class Service : ServiceBase
{
    System.Timers.Timer workingQueueTimer;

    public Service()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        workingQueueTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        workingQueueTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(workingQueueTimer_Elapsed);
        workingQueueTimer.Interval = 1000;
        workingQueueTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    void workingQueueTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        workingQueueTimer.Enabled = false;

        DoWork();

        workingQueueTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private static void DoWork()
    {
        //finish workingqueueitems
        WorkingQueue.ProcessFinishedItems();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        workingQueueTimer.Stop();
        workingQueueTimer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: "I was thinking I ran out of thread but I have a good 1000 left" where did you get that number?

Comment: your code is a mess. remove thread initialization,while(true),Thread.sleep. your timer is late the time DoWork need to complete!

Comment: -Scott: I used the ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads().
-giammin: As I said my knowledge is limited. Could you explain reasons as to why I need this? The timers.threading was a test since the timers.timer behaved slowly. I'll update the code so it shows both examples.

Comment: why you should run out of thread if you create only one thread?

Comment: if I use your timer code in a console application with the dowork method that prints datetime.now I get it everyseconds. As I said before your dowork method takes 25 sec to complete or you are seeing database data cached (db and service are on the same pc?). Please post your WorkingQueue.ProcessFinishedItems(); code

Comment: If things are on different computers, could it be that the system times aren't in sync? For example, you could be using the database server's time for one value and the other computer's time for another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be due to:

- your **DoWork()** method takes 25 sec to complete
- You are seeing the db data cached in someway or a transaction is delaying it
- your method **WorkingQueue.ProcessFinishedItems()** is taking the wrong rows to update
- if your service and db are in separeted machine they have a different time clock of 25 sec

Comment: I figured out the problem now :)
The database (and websites) are on a other server, and that servers clock is 26 seconds behind mine, and then my service on my developer pc triggers it later. Damn windows clocks!

Comment: @Gucchi :D Your code is good but use the timer one, it is better than while(true) and thread.sleep